# Show URL in browser when link added with javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, statusbar

I have added an onclick function to a div here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("fab").onclick = function() {
  location.href = 'http://your.url.here';
}
</script>
```

When you hover over the div, it doesnt show the URL in the bottom left of the browser like an anchor tag does (see picture): https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGLHS.png

Is there any way to make the browser show the link, when it has been added with javascript?

Comment: You are not actually adding a _link_ by doing this - you are adding an event handler to something that may or may not be a link.

Comment: Add an anchor to your DOM with the link as href Attribute and trigger a mouseenter event on it. jquery will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something different. I hope i didnt understand it wrong. If you add -a- element as parent to your -div- it acts like what you want.

```
var element = document.getElementById("fab");
var aa = document.createElement("a");
aa.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com');
var parent = element.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(aa, element);
aa.appendChild(element);
```

please let me know if i understand it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Add the `title` attribute to your element:

```
<div id="fab" title="http://your.url.here'></div>
```

Actually this *is* different than the popup you're seeing, but it might be as close as you can get.

As [@Benten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31125388/497356) points out, you'd have to set `window.status`, which isn't allowed by most modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew, I gave the window.status a go, but as you say it doesn't work in most browsers these days.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly access the property that you are looking for any more. Usually it's ignored. See this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp . I'd say the other answer is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks Benten for confirming that this no longer works in most browsers.